# How many Auras can enchant one Creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I played Magic: The Gathering with couple of friends.
I was asked a question when we came to a situation where we could put two Auras on one Creature. Can one enchant a create with more than one Aura?

Answer (score 10):

You can have any number of Enchantments attached to a given Creature, unless the cards themselves say otherwise.

Comment: Also Gatherer of Graces and Auramancer's Guise would be useless if it wan't possible

Comment: @IvoBeckers, Daybreak Coronet would be even _more_ useless, since it can't even remain attached to a creature that doesn't have another aura attached.

Comment: It wouldn't even be possible to play Daybreak Coronet at all.

Comment: @murgatroid99, It's worse than not being able to play it. You can't even attach it through an effect such as Sun Titan. Daybreak Coronet also gets dumped into the graveyard if it becomes the only aura on a creature.

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can! 
That's it, if the cards don't state otherwise and the creature is a valid target for every one of the enchantments. And as you can cast several enchantments on the same turn you even can do it on just one turn.There's no a thing like a 'limit' on the number of enchantments one can cast over a given creature. 
Just consider strategic-wise if it's convenient for you to put two or more auras on a creature that could be wiped out by a single card from your adversary.

Answer (score -4):

It is applicable to creatures only. But for Global Enchantment based on the old rule of MTG from 4th to 5th edition, you can only play one enchantment per type per game. for Example, you can play one pestilence during the game and can no longer play another one while it's still in play (because it doesn't make sense right?). I never saw another rule out there that overrides this rule but I'm seeing a lot of players who does not abide by this rule.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was never true of enchantments in general. There are specific enchantments called World Enchantments (originally "Enchant World") such as [Concordant Crossroads](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=2827), and only one of those can be on the battlefield at a time.

Comment: Yes, I believe you've confused World Enchantments with regular enchantments. You certainly can have multiple Pestilences on the battlefield at once, and you've always been allowed to. Though you're right that in general, having multiple of that specific one isn't helpful.

Comment: This was only ever true of cards typed "Enchant World" A lot of enchantments would be redundant to have multiple copies of out, but just because it doesn't make sense to play that second pestilence doesn't mean you aren't allowed to, just that it'd be a bad idea to do since you'd have to sacrifice both when there are no creatures left.